# Is possible to rewrite the code so as to reduce the number of selects?

Tags: c#, linq

However this code tested correctly I am wondering about there is something is not correct, because 3 nested SELECT(). Is possible to rewrite the code with 2 nested SELECT()?

```
var sums = Enumerable.Range(1, int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
    .Select(x => Console.ReadLine())
        .Select(y => y.Split(' ')
           .Select(int.Parse).Sum());
```

Comment: You don't have three nested `Select`s, you have two...

Comment: And you can combine first two of them if you need sum of all numbers.

Comment: _[Can I post questions about **optimizing code** on Stack Overflow?....No, it isn't the best place - though it is on-topic, there's a better place for such questions.  You can take working code to Code Review - but do make sure to read their help center to see what exactly they expect from a good question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_.  You are unlikely to get improvement if your intent is for _performance_ or rewrite via tricky _sugar syntax_

Comment: @MickyDuncan, sugar syntax? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the ReadLine with the Split:

```
var sums = Enumerable.Range(1, int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
    .Select(x => Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).Sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine first and second

```
 var sums = Enumerable.Range(1, int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
             .Select(x => Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Convert<Int64>().Sum());
```

If you need just total sum ( which is not what your current code is doing)

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(1, int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
      .SelectMany(x=>Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Convert<Int64>())
      .Sum()
```

Comment: The sum of a list of ints can be larger than the maximum size of an int.

Comment: Have array of string this method? Is it same as Convert.ToInt32?